# How to split very large JSON file in R?

Tags: json, r

I am currently working with Amazon User Metadata of size roughly around 9 GB. I have this data in .json format and want to read in R, due to such huge volume of data I want to divide the files in small chunks (either by size or by number of elements). If you can help me out how can I do this in R. The format of file is as follows:

```
{

"asin": "0000031852",

 "title": "Girls Ballet Tutu Zebra Hot Pink",

  "price": 3.17,

  "imUrl": "http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51fAmVkTbyL._SY300_.jpg",

  "related":

  {

    "also_bought": ["B00JHONN1S", "B002BZX8Z6", "B00D2K1M3O", "0000031909", "B00613WDTQ", "B00D0WDS9A", "B00D0GCI8S", "0000031895", "B003AVKOP2", "B003AVEU6G", "B003IEDM9Q", "B002R0FA24", "B00D23MC6W", "B00D2K0PA0", "B00538F5OK", "B00CEV86I6", "B002R0FABA", "B00D10CLVW", "B003AVNY6I", "B002GZGI4E", "B001T9NUFS", "B002R0F7FE", "B00E1YRI4C", "B008UBQZKU", "B00D103F8U", "B007R2RM8W"],

    "also_viewed": ["B002BZX8Z6", "B00JHONN1S", "B008F0SU0Y", "B00D23MC6W", "B00AFDOPDA", "B00E1YRI4C", "B002GZGI4E", "B003AVKOP2", "B00D9C1WBM", "B00CEV8366", "B00CEUX0D8", "B0079ME3KU", "B00CEUWY8K", "B004FOEEHC", "0000031895", "B00BC4GY9Y", "B003XRKA7A", "B00K18LKX2", "B00EM7KAG6", "B00AMQ17JA", "B00D9C32NI", "B002C3Y6WG", "B00JLL4L5Y", "B003AVNY6I", "B008UBQZKU", "B00D0WDS9A", "B00613WDTQ", "B00538F5OK", "B005C4Y4F6", "B004LHZ1NY", "B00CPHX76U", "B00CEUWUZC", "B00IJVASUE", "B00GOR07RE", "B00J2GTM0W", "B00JHNSNSM", "B003IEDM9Q", "B00CYBU84G", "B008VV8NSQ", "B00CYBULSO", "B00I2UHSZA", "B005F50FXC", "B007LCQI3S", "B00DP68AVW", "B009RXWNSI", "B003AVEU6G", "B00HSOJB9M", "B00EHAGZNA", "B0046W9T8C", "B00E79VW6Q", "B00D10CLVW", "B00B0AVO54", "B00E95LC8Q", "B00GOR92SO", "B007ZN5Y56", "B00AL2569W", "B00B608000", "B008F0SMUC", "B00BFXLZ8M"],
    "bought_together": ["B002BZX8Z6"]

  },

  "salesRank": {"Toys & Games": 211836},

  "brand": "Coxlures",

  "categories": [["Sports & Outdoors", "Other Sports", "Dance"]]

}
```

Comment: Does `rjson::fromJSON` help?

Comment: Try the `jq` package. It can stream in JSON records and you can chunk them out to files.

Comment: If I try to load using rjosn my laptop freezes, RAM usage becomes 90% and Hard Disk usage 100%. @Christoph

Comment: Please provide your json data as `dput(data)`. Then I can have a look at it...